# Button click not redirecting to next page in Selenium IDE

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

I am using `clickAndWait` for `xpath=//button[contains(.,'Next')]` When I click Find on Selenium IDE the button is found, but the script doesn't click on the button. The button has `id = pmc_wizard_next` and `class = btn btn-next`.

The html for the button is:

```
<div id="pmc_wizard" class="wizard pmc-wizard">

    <ul class="steps pmc-wizard-steps"> … </ul>
    <div class="actions pmc-wizard-actions">
        <button id="pmc_wizard_prev" class="btn btn-prev"> … </button>
        <button id="pmc_wizard_next" class="btn btn-next" data-last="Submit">

            Next

            <i class="icon-arrow-right"></i>
        </button>
    </div>

</div>
```

When the button is clicked, it doesn't navigate to the next page, however it does perform all the actions on the next page.

What should I be doing?

Comment: Try using `submit()` rather than `click()`.

Comment: Hi stray. i am using Selenium IDE and submit is not working. i am currently using Command: click and Target: css=button#pmc_wizard_next.btn.btn-next. is there any better way to hit that button?

Comment: Btw. it turns out my button gets disabled in the middle of the execution and then gets enabled again. i have put in a pause statement when i know its going to be disabled. But still it wont hit the button.

Answer (score 1):

There are some instances where selenium (watir) refuses to click a link or a button even when the xpath expression is valid and claims it found the object.

In these situations I just use a jquery .click function with the .executeScript method as a work around.

Comment: not working in IE in my case